# Sister living with me, but should my parents pay me?

Tags: united-kingdom

My sister is living with me and my partner due to her and my dad not getting along. She's 15 and my mum also lives with our dad.

Should I be getting anything from our parents for letting her live here, feed her, let her have her friends round etc.. I am basically taking over the mother role and they don't seem to care what happens with her .. sad .

Comment: There are some other sites in the stack exchange network that might have answers to this question: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you could. In your shoes, I probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

As she is under 16, her parents (or other people with parental responsibility) are responsible for feeding and housing her (and making sure she goes to school).

On the other hand, there is probably no way to legally force them to make a contribution to your costs.  Your only option would be to throw your sister out, and make them take her back.

On the other other hand, the fact they *are* legally responsible, may be enough to enable you to get a contribution from them.

My final thought is that mediation may be helpful - it might be worth speaking to Citizens Advice or even Social Services to see if there is a mediation service available.

Comment: Even her parents can refuse custody. City or state will rule and she will end up under Social Services or its equivalent organization/body.